# Understanding Applicative Functor in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, functor, applicative

Suppose I need to write some functions to invoke a few REST APIs: `api1`, `api2`, `api3`.

```
def api1(url: Url) = ???
def api2(url: Url) = ???
def api3(url: Url) = ???
```

Suppose for simplicity that I use my own simplified class `Url`:

```
case class Url(host: String, port: Int, path: Path)
```

In order to construct a `Url` I read `host` and `port` from configuration and call functions `api1`, `api2`, `api3`, which add required `paths` and invoke their APIs:

```
def api1(host: String, port: Int) = ???
def api2(host: String, port: Int) = ???
def api3(host: String, port: Int) = ???

val (host, port) = ... // read from the configuration

// call the APIs
api1(host, port) 
api2(host, port)
api3(host, port)
```

It is much better though to use a function `Path => Url` (or `builder pattern` if we write in `Java`) in order to *hide* the `host` and `port` and other details of constructing `Url`.

```
def api1(f: Path => Url) = ...
def api2(f: Path => Url) = ...
def api3(f: Path => Url) = ...
```

It is easy to implement such function `f: Path => Url` with *curring*

```
val url: String => Int => Path = (Url.apply _).curried
val (host, port) = ... // from the configuration
val f = url(host, port)
api1(f)
api2(f)
api3(f)
```

So far, so good but what if have *optional* host and port ?

```
val (hostOpt: Option[String], portOpt: Option[Int]) = ... // from configuration
```

Now we have a function `String => Int => Path => Url` and `Option[String]` and `Option[Int]`. How to get `Path => Url` ?

Let's ask a slightly different question: How to get `Option[Path => Url]` given `String => Int => Path => Url`, `Option[String]`, and `Option[Int]` ?

Fortunately we can define such an operation easily:

```
trait Option[A] { ... def ap[B](of: Option[A => B]): Option[B] = ??? }
```

Given this `ap` we can answer the original question:

```
 val of: Option[Path => Url] = portOpt ap (hostOpt ap Some(url) 
 of.map(f => api1(f))
 of.map(f => api2(f))
 of.map(f => api3(f))
```

Speaking abstractly, we have used the fact that `Option` is an *applicative functor*. `M` is an applicative functor if it is a functor and has two additional operations:

- `ap` to get `M[B]` given `M[A => B]` and `M[A]`
- `pure` to get `M[A => B]` from `A => B` (`Some` for `Option`)

These operations should comply with two simple laws but it's another story.

...

Does it make sense ?

Comment: That sounds right, but just for reference, you can simplify the syntax a bit. Using scalaz for applicative functors: `case class Url(host: String, port: Int, path: Path); /* emulating config with _.some */ ("foo.com".some |@| 8080.some)(Function.uncurried(Url.curried))`

Comment: Using `scalaz` and its `ApplicativeBuilder` is yet another story (or even two stories). BTW I am not sure yet I want to recommend the `ApplicativeBuilder` with its `|@|` syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds pretty reasonable to me, although I'm not sure if there's much of a question here, which is its own kind of problem.

I'm making this an answer instead of a comment because there's one thing worth noting. For many types there's a reason to avoid monadic binding and stick to `ap` beyond just "using less powerful abstractions is the right thing to do".

For example: the standard library future API's `zip` is an applicative operator that allows you to run futures in parallel, and if you use `bar() zip foo()` instead of `for { f <- foo(); b <- bar() } yield (f, b)` you can actually speed up your program (in many cases). For other types, using the applicative functor stuff instead of monadic bind offers other kinds of possibilities for optimization.

This isn't really the case with `Option`. It wouldn't be unreasonable to define `ap` in terms of `flatMap`. Using the applicative combinators is still "the right thing to do", but `flatMap` is right there and doesn't need extra definitions or dependencies and `for`-comprehensions are so simple and clean. There's just not the same kind of payoff that you see for things like futures.

Comment: But if you stick to the most general abstraction of your code, you might be able to replace `Option` by some applicative but non-mondic type-class in the future. Yes, it's not very likely...